# Package babel error - bbding.sty not found

Tags: errors, babel

I am a new user to ubuntu. I installed latex as I had it before (I was a windows user). This document was perfectly fine in windows, no error. And now I tried to open the same document in ubuntu and there appears some error. I have no idea why and how to fix it. And I don't think the problem is in the "usepackage{bm}", because if I delete it, the red line appears in the other line. Thank you for your advices.

[image]

Comment: For the `babel` error you probably need to install the package [`babel-czech`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-czech). The other error talks about `bbding`, so is probably not about the line `\usepackage{bm}` but about the line above (`\usepackage{bbding}`). You'll need to install [`bbding`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bbding). Depending on how exactly you installed TeX what you have to do to install these packages varies.

Comment: well as the error says "bbding,sty" is not found. To install the package. Or don't use it, if you don't need it. You need also to install czech support.

Comment: **If** you installed a 'vanilla' TeX live, you can probably just say `tlmgr install babel-czech bbding` and are good. **But** if you installed TeX live via `apt` (`apt-get`) you need to find the Ubuntu package that ships these packages (try `texlive-lang-czechslovak` and `texlive-fonts-extra`).